# Why won't the color of my navbar links change

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors, navbar

So this is the HTML I have right now. I am trying to change specific links in the navbar. The "font-family", "line-height", and "font-size" all work, but the color of the links will not change.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-left"><img src="resources/assets/yf_logo.svg"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Programs</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Shelter</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Drop-ins</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Street Outreach</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Community Partners</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="textstyle16"><a href="#">Get Involved</a></li>
            <li class="textstyle16"><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li class="textstyle16"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="textstyle18"><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Here is my first css

```
    .textstyle16 {
font-family:"montserrat-regular";
font-size:18px;
line-height:21px;
color:#474747;
```

here is my second css

```
    .textstyle18 {
font-family:"montserrat-regular";
font-size:18px;
line-height:21px; 
color:#ffffff;
    }
```

Comment: There is no font:#fffff; option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.textstyle16 a` or  `.textstyle16 a:link` as a selector. The links are *child elements* of the `.textstyle16` elements, they don't have that class themselves, and there is a color declaration for `a` tags in the browsers default styles which applies if you don't use these selectors.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `color:` (not `font:`).

Answer (score 1):

It is probably being overwritten elsewhere in your code. Add `!important` to the color definition. If this correct the color, then yes, it's being overwritten somewhere in your styles.

Right-click the link and "inspect" the link in Google Chrome or Firefox. You'll be able to see which styles are being applied to the link specifically.

Example:

[image]